# Remote MySQL access not respondto MySQL client

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I have a remote Server which is running mysql. I have enabled remote access by changing the bind address to the public ip, and commenting the "skip-networking" line. I then used ufw (ubuntu firewall) to open the mysql port 3306

However my client times out when trying to connect to the server. So I test the connection with telnet, and I get the expect response, the same as I get on the local server.

I'm getting no errors, and no response when using a mysql client, but access would appear to be there in telnet.

Can anybody suggest what I've missed?

Thanks

Comment: what is the exact message when "my client times out when trying to connect to the server" ?

Comment: I would go another route. Instead of opening up mysql to the public I would ssh into the server and then connect locally

Comment: @dragonfly are you sure that the mysql user you use to connect from that host has the necessary rights ?

Comment: I thought I had set the user up correctly I will re-investigate the users, I did use '%' for the host because my local ip address is not static.

Answer (score 0):

If its not a firewall issue then maybe its a permission problem , try this for the user you use to connect from that host:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'host' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
GRANT ALL on *.* to 'user'@'host';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**UPDATE:**

Also check the [bind-address](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) from `my.cnf` file

> For example, if you bind to 0.0.0.0, you can connect to the server
>   using all existing accounts. But if you bind to 127.0.0.1, the server
>   accepts connections only on that address. In this case, first make
>   sure that the 'root'@'127.0.0.1' account is present in the mysql.user
>   table so that you can still connect to the server to shut it down.

Comment: I assumed that I would get an access denied type error if I had got the privileges wrong, but I may be wrong. I have previously used GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'username'@'%';  However using SHOW GRANTS nothing is showing up for username. Looks like my privileges aren't updating.

Comment: I did flush when I first did the grant, and I've just retried it, and still no difference. Using SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user; I can see username with the host % which implies the user is setup correctly.

Comment: i agree, are you sure you did telnet from the client to the server on port 3306 and it was ok ? also check the `bind-address` parameter in `my.cnf`

Comment: Yes I telneted from my local machine and got Trying 46.249.60.94...
Connected to 46.249.60.94.
Escape character is '^]'.
[
5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1$?[*_#,R�j'#xU!AdU\NSmysql_native_passwordConnection closed by foreign host.
(I wish I could use code tags in a comment) which is more or less what I'd expect. I checked the IP in the bind address, that was okay, but to be sure I changed it to 0.0.0.0 so any ip should work. And restarted mysql. Still no luck.

Comment: Could it be a routing issue??

Comment: I think so.. i do not see any other issue so please check what device you have between the client and the server (switch,router) and you need to open the port 3306

Comment: But how does telnet connect if this is the case. I can connect to other servers, so I would suggest that the problem isn't at my location, but more on the server. Is it possible some sort of routing problem on the server?

Comment: Actually there is a case when telnet works but the connection doesn't (but its very unlikely in this case) : when the network traffic is monitored and based on some filters the connection is dropped ... but again its very unlikely in this case. Since telnet is working the problem is on the server , as you said, so i suggest to double check the permissions because i do not see any other options

Comment: Well I've rechecked the permissions, not sure how I can test them without a remote connection. From the commandline executing exactly the same line (i.e specifying the public ip address as host) works instantly, try it from any remote location, and it fails.

Comment: this just occurred to me : i assume that the used used has a password but when you executed `GRANT ALL ON . TO 'username'@'%';` if no password was previously set then when you connect you do not need a pw

Comment: When I couldn't see the grant table before I was logged in as root. If I now log in locally as the new user, I can see the user setup with all privileges and with the "identified by password....." section. So I suspect the password is setup correctly. I still tried it without a password. And no luck. My gut feeling is it isn't even getting as far as authenticating, as I would guess that I would get an "Access Denied" error if it was, and also deliberately using the wrong password makes no difference.

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*12345678' - I have changed the username and password hash, but otherwise that is pasted as from the grant table. The password has does have the leading asterix as I pasted it.

Comment: pls read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html it has some helpful stuff like  " Make sure that the server has not been configured to ignore network connections or (if you are attempting to connect remotely) that it has not been configured to listen only locally on its network interfaces. If the server was started with --skip-networking, it will not accept TCP/IP connections at all. If the server was started with --bind-address=127.0.0.1, it will listen for TCP/IP connections only locally on the loopback interface and will not accept remote connections."

Comment: Hmmm - I hate errors like this. I worked through the page you suggested, till I got the the section about using mysqladim to get the version etc. and that give me access denied. Rerean it with username and password and it worked fine. Try a mysql login from the commandline and that works now. So I have no idea what's changed, and what was wrong, bit it works now. Thanks very much for you patience and time working through this. Even though I can tell you what fixed it, it is now fixed. Once again thanks for the help.

Comment: np :) its a shame that we didn't found the cause because i was curious

Comment: So am I but unfortunately we can't fix what is nolonger broken - Still atleast it works now. Once again thanks for the help.